# How to highlight a row in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

The code below seems to have no effect.  I want it to be highlighed in the same way it highlights when you tap on a row

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   ...
   [cell.textLabel setHighlighted:YES];


   return cell;
}
```

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845773/how-to-initially-select-a-row-in-uitableview) might help.

Answer (score 30):

This line will handle repainting the cell, label and accessory for you:

```
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

Answer (score 21):

As others have noted, you can programmatically select a cell using this method:

```
 [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

However, you should be careful **not to call this method too soon.**

The first time that the view controller containing said `tableView` is `initialized`, the earliest that you should call this method is within `viewDidAppear:`.

So, you should do something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]; // set to whatever you want to be selected first 
   [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO  scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```

If you try putting this call into `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear:`, or any other early view lifecycle calls, it will likely not work or have odd results (such as scrolling to the correct position but not selecting the cell).

Comment: On iOS 9 seems to work from `viewWillApear` and `viewDidAppear ` and not from `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 15):

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection: 0];

[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

usually works

If you are using interface builder to build your interface, one thing to check is that you specified the view of the table view controller. If you don't actually specify the view, this selection message may go nowhere.

(you specify the view by selecting the table view controller in the interface builder inspector window and dragging the outlet for "view" to the table view you want to do the selection in).

Answer (score 3):

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  // do something here
}
```

Try this :)

Comment: Only available in iOS 6 http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   ...
   [cell.textLabel setHighlighted:YES];


   return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices. Either use the selection of the table view:

```
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath animated: YES scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

Or change the background color of the table cell in the table view delegate:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = ...
}
```