# select a row from view when a push notification is received

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am trying to select a row from a table view when a push notification is received.

I have myprojectAppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "iw.h"
#import "Bookmark.h"


@interface myprojectAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
    UIWindow               *window;
    UITabBarController     *tabBarController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
    NSMutableArray                  *tableData;
    NSMutableArray                  *imagesList;
    IBOutlet Bookmark               *tableCell;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow               *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController     *tabBarController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray                  *tableData;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray                  *imagesList;

- (BOOL)getIsLaunched;
- (void)showService;
- (void)showMessage;
- (void) loadLogoList;
+ (const NSString*)getVersion;
+ (const NSString*)getXMLversionURL;
+ (NSMutableDictionary *)logos;
+ (void)setLogos:(NSMutableDictionary *)newDictionary;
- (void)checkVersion;

@end
```

and implementing the didReceiveRemoteNotification  in  myprojectAppDelegate.m file
But the tableview is implemented in another class bookmarklist.m when the app start after launch options it navigates to bookmarklist.m and displays the table view.

I want to access that tableview which is in bookmarklist.m and select a row in the table when ever i receive a push notification.

please help me with this. i am new to ios programming.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an observer method in your `bookmarklist.m` class like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(newMessageReceived:) name:@"NEWMESSAGE" object:nil];
```

and add this observer method in the same class

```
-(void)newMessageReceived:(NSNotification *) notification{
       //Here you can select the row you want to be selected
}
```

Then in your `didReceiveRemoteNotification` in `appDelegate` file, post a notification like this and pass the data you want to post in object parameter.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NEWMESSAGE" object:nil];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i am trying your method, do i need to add the first line in tableview method?

Comment: got that thought after adding the comment :P

Comment: and also can i possibly send an integer variable from didReceiveRemoteNotification to this method -(void)newMessageReceived:(NSNotification *) notification?

Comment: Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287741/passing-data-using-notification-iphone

Answer (score 1):

Use the UITableView class method:

`- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

This will return the cell at the indexPath you give it.

If you only want to select the cell, use this class method:

```
- (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition
```

Comment: i am new if you don't mind could you elaborate or guide me to a link or tutorial?

Comment: You will need to combine the 2 answers. Set up the notification like HRM suggest, use my UITableView methods to select your cell.

Comment: You'll find more info on how to select your cell at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518723/how-to-highlight-a-row-in-a-uitableview

Comment: Great, glad to have been of assistance