# App stops running when put into background

Tags: ios

I am making a clock application; with a stopwatch and timer. When my app goes into the background (ie. the user goes onto the homescreen, switches to another app, or locks the phone), the timer and stopwatch stop counting. I know several apps that continue working after it has been put into the background.

Is there a setting I can change to keep it running?

Comment: This will help you: [Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios)

Comment: Your app needs to update the display when it comes from the foreground. Basically keep track of the time it went into the background and update accordingly when it comes into the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Create variable like

```
self.timeBeforeGoingBackgound = [NSDate date];
```

Then you can get time using

```
[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:self.timeBeforeGoingBackgound];
```

Comment: This won't work if the app is killed in the background and then fully restarted. The date needs to be persisted.

Comment: can read/write it in unserdefaults instead of a variable... this will work

Comment: @samfisher Exactly. The value needs to be persisted. `NSUserDefaults` is a good place for that.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer for exact your question is **NO** You cann't make your application perform some action while it is in background mode.

[Here you can find Apple's Doc, which says what can work in background.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22)

Also for your case it is easy to implement stopwatch saving current time for example in `NSUserDefaults` when this AppDelegate's method  `applicationDidEnterBackground` is called and to update elapsed time in `applicationDidBecomeActive` method

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to save your state when you go into the background and then restore the state when you come back into the foreground. This means both timers and the actually timing data.

Answer (score 0):

Adding code for George's answer:

In your `applicationDidEnterBackground`

```
NSDate *currentDate= [NSDate date];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:currentDate forKey:@"backgroundDate"];
```

And in your `applicationDidBecomeActive`

```
NSDate *dateWhenAppGoesBg= (NSDate *)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"backgroundDate"];
NSTimeInterval timeSpentInBackground = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:dateWhenAppGoesBg];
```

Now you have the `timeSpentInBackground` in seconds, from which you can update the UI or do the rest of tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how do I access `timeSpentInBackground` in my viewController.m file?

Comment: You can post a NSNotification from applicationDidBecomeActive. Please check my answer in this post on how to use this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702022/select-a-row-from-view-when-a-push-notification-is-received/17703073#17703073.

Comment: I don't quite know how to implement this, what parts go in the AppDelegate, and what parts go in my viewcontroller.m?

Comment: You need to register a notification method in your viewcontroller.m and from applicationDidBecomeActive in ur appDelegate post a notification. So viewcontroller.m notification method will get called and you can use the value there. Is it clear?

Comment: Kinda, how is the variable being passed? I'm quite confused

Comment: Check out the answer for this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272068/pass-nsstring-variable-to-other-class-with-nsnotification

Comment: I get this error when I pass timeSpentInBackground as the object: Sending 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'double') to parameter of incompatible type 'id'

Comment: You can't pass NSTimeInterval as its a typedef of double. You need to pass it like as NSNumber like this NSNumber *n = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:yourTimeIntervalValue];