# How to use Objective C in an AppleScript-Cocoa Application?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript, applescript-objc

I am developing an Applescript application using X-Code and I'm having the hardest time finding answers to questions. It's tough because I'm struggling to understand how the UI elements work, etc., and most answers to those questions are written in Objective C. I have learned a little bit about how to convert Objective C code into Applescript, but in most cases I'm still not sure.

For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4518762/1319622) shows some ObjC code, but I don't know how to make use of it in my Applescript application.

Is there a resource or guide that can help me to a) understand how to use Objective C code in my Applescript app, and/or b) how to rewrite Objective C code in Applescript?

Comment: I would use Objective-C, but here is a book that I see recommended a lot to learn how to use AppleScriptObjC: http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/

Comment: The book you recommended is great. I bought it and am going through it. Thanks so much. If this were an answer I would accept it!

Comment: I think I am having the same problem I could not figure out how to update one label in a window using AppleScript

Answer (score 2):

In general, Applescript can be used to automate tasks (especially repetitive ones) for any MacOS application that exposes an Applescript dictionary.

One can compile and execute Applescript from within MacOS applications written in Objective-C ([via the NSApplescript class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsapplescript_Class/Reference/Reference.html), but the other way around, one would use Applescript to *call into* an already existing app (or one that you created yourself) that was written in Objective-C.

It sounds like you should write the lowest level stuff natively in Objective-C and see if you can automate that from within Obj-C, [or expose an Applescript dictionary](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/smile/external_codes/projects_xcode_sdef.html) (via an sdef file that gets included in the Xcode project) and then you can use Applescript to do things via your native app.

Makes sense?